# How to handle the type converter when Json array is empty in kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

```
class TotalCaseConverters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun listToJsonString(value: MutableList<Tech>?): String =  Gson().toJson(value)

    @TypeConverter
    fun jsonStringToList(value: String) = Gson().fromJson(value, 
    Array<Tech>::class.java).toList()
}
```

Error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while computing database live
> data.
> at
> androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData.refreshRunnable$lambda$0(RoomTrackingLiveData.kt:74)
> at
> androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData.$r8$lambda$PhMGW5zFk4QWazERd2lfEeLZqW0(Unknown
> Source:0)
> at
> androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown
> Source:2)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
> **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Gson().fromJson(value,
> Array::class.java) must not be null**
> at
> com.averigo.mgmt.models.caseManagement.TotalCaseConverters.jsonStringToList(TotalCase.kt:115)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fromJson() returns null if json string is null or empty. Therefore you can decide what return value is needed. The first option is set nullable `?` to model, dao methods and converter. The second option is return an empty list when the json string is null or empty.

```kotlin
@ProvidedTypeConverter
class TotalCaseConverters {
    
    @TypeConverter
    fun listToJsonString(value: MutableList<Tech>?): String {
        return Gson().toJson(value)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun jsonStringToList(value: String?): List<Tech> {
        val jsonString = if (value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            "[]" // present empty list in json syntax
        } else {
            value
        }
        return Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Array<Tech>::class.java).toList()
    }
}
```